# dbeaver not show error when create function oracle with error

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I create function in Dbeaver  for oracle which has errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function tmp_pra  RETURN  NUMBER  AS 
DECLARE 
m$a NUMBER (1);
BEGIN 
    m$a :=1;
    RETURN m$a; WWW
END;    
/
```

Run Sql Query(ctrl+enter).
Dbeaver run this query and not show error.
When I open schema find this function and  Compile Function(ctrl+f9) then show error in function.
How to immediately get an error when Run Sql Query(ctrl+enter).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a missing feature of DBeaver and there is a feature request since some year: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3721.
You can fetch compilation errors manually with

```
select * from USER_ERRORS 
 where NAME = upper('tmp_pra')  -- use your function/procedure name
   and TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

Valid values for TYPE are:

```
FUNCTION
PROCEDURE
PACKAGE BODY
TYPE BODY
VIEW
```

Alternatively, you can Ctrl+Click the procedure name, go to "Declaration", Save it and click "Persist" when asked (or Ctrl-F9 to compile): at this time, Dbeaver will show compilation errors. But this is not user-friendly as well, especially when the code is in a file I am editing.